# How to set the default schema for calcite ReflectiveSchema?

Tags: apache-calcite

It seems the defaultSchema property does not work.

```
public void main(String[] args){
    public final String sql4 = "select count(e.empid) from emps as e";

Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");
            Properties info = new Properties();
            info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");
            info.setProperty(CalciteConnectionProperty.CASE_SENSITIVE.camelName(), "false");
            info.setProperty("defaultSchema", "hr");
            try {
                Connection connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
                CalciteConnection conn =
                    connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
                SchemaPlus rootSchema = conn.getRootSchema();
                Schema schema = new ReflectiveSchema(new HrSchema(emps1, depts1));
                rootSchema.add("hr", schema);
                
                test4(conn);
                
                connection.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
}
public void test4(CalciteConnection conn) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql4);
        while(rs.next()) {
            
        }
        rs.close();
        statement.close();
    }
```

we got the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: Error while executing SQL "select count(e.empid) from emps as e": From line 1, column 28 to line 1, column 31: Object 'emps' not found
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:163)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeQuery(AvaticaStatement.java:227)
at com.xsmartware.javatest.calcite.CalCiteTest.test4(CalCiteTest.java:118)
at com.xsmartware.javatest.calcite.CalCiteTest.run(CalCiteTest.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:758)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:748)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
at com.xsmartware.javatest.JavaTestApplication.main(JavaTestApplication.java:9)
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 28 to line 1, column 31: Object 'emps' not found
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:505)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:932)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:917)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.newValidationError(SqlValidatorImpl.java:5266)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.resolveImpl(IdentifierNamespace.java:183)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.validateImpl(IdentifierNamespace.java:188)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate(AbstractNamespace.java:89)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1100)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1071)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3375)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3357)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateSelect(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3639)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SelectNamespace.validateImpl(SelectNamespace.java:64)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate(AbstractNamespace.java:89)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1100)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1071)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect.validate(SqlSelect.java:247)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateScopedExpression(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1046)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validate(SqlValidatorImpl.java:752)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:586)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:257)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:220)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:647)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:513)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:483)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:249)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl.prepareAndExecute(CalciteMetaImpl.java:623)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:674)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:156)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Object 'emps' not found
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:505)
at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex(Resources.java:599)
... 37 more

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `setSchema` method on the `CalciteConnection` object.

Add the following statement to fix the above code:

```
conn.setSchema("hr");
```